# How to extract the subreddits I am subscribed to with the Python PRAW library?

Tags: python, api, documentation, reddit, praw

I am a pretty novice programmer so I figured that Python would be my best bet to find do this side project of mine. For context, I was suspended from Reddit a few years ago and want to use a new account. To do this I want to get all of the subreddits my old account was subscribed to and then subscribe to those subreddits on my new account. As of right now I am unsure how to access my subreddits using PRAW and couldn't find anything related to it on the PRAW documentation, but I did find this on the Reddit API documentation: https://www.reddit.com/dev/api#GET_subreddits_mine_subscriber.

I'm guessing that I am having trouble connecting the dots between the PRAW API wrapper and the basic Reddit API code. Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests 
import praw 

def authorized():

    reddit = praw.Reddit(
        client_id = 'RXv8w855SBV_*********',
        client_secret = 'rWiK0nuxh8X0snK-************',
        password = '***',
        user_agent = 'GetSubs/0.01',
    username = 'fearthecooper')

    return reddit

def get_self(reddit = authorized()):
    redditor = reddit.redditor('fearthecooper')

reddit = authorized()
redditor = reddit.redditor('fearthecooper')

redditor.subscriber()
```

The very last line is where I am having trouble. I tried a few random attempts at a method to get the subs but was unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a link to the PRAW documentation that should solve this problem. https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/stable/code_overview/reddit/user.html#praw.models.User.subreddits

EDIT:
you need to use subreddits() method on User object in Reddit authenicated user - you don't need me() to be called.

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(
  client_id=...,
  client_secret=...,
  refresh_token=...,
  user_agent=...
)

print(list(reddit.user.subreddits()))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).